# Python click application required parameters have precedence over sub command help option

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm building a [click 7.x](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/) application with [Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/) and am having some issues getting help to work for sub commands. I have a global option that is required and this option is being reported as missing when I run help on any sub command.

For example, given the following dummy script `cli.py`:

```py
import click


@click.group()
@click.option('--directory', required=True)
def cli(directory):
    """
    this is a tool that has an add and remove command
    """
    click.echo(directory)


@cli.command()
@click.overwrite('--overwrite', is_flag=True)
def add(overwrite):
    """
    this is the add command
    """
    click.echo("add overwrite={}".format(overwrite))


@cli.command()
def remove():
    """
    this is the remove command
    """
    click.echo('remove')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

When I run the following:

```
python cli.py --help
```

I get the desired output of:

```
Usage cli.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  this is a tool that has an add and remove command

Options:
  --directory TEXT  [required]
  --help            Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  add     this is the add command
  remove  this is the remove command
```

But if I run this:

```
python cli.py add --help
```

I get the following error:

```
Usage cli.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try "cli.py --help" for help.

Error: Missing option "--directory"
```

How do I get the help for the add command to show without having to supply the `--directory` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom `click.Group` class to ignore the required args when `--help` is requested like:

#### Custom Class:

```
class IgnoreRequiredWithHelp(click.Group):
    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        try:
            return super(IgnoreRequiredWithHelp, self).parse_args(ctx, args)
        except click.MissingParameter as exc:
            if '--help' not in args:
                raise

            # remove the required params so that help can display
            for param in self.params:
                param.required = False
            return super(IgnoreRequiredWithHelp, self).parse_args(ctx, args)
```

#### Using the Custom Class:

To use the custom class, pass it as the `cls` argument to the group decorator like:

```
@click.group(cls=IgnoreRequiredWithHelp)
....
def my_group():
    ....
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Group.parse_args()` and catch the `click.MissingParameter` exception.  We then negate the `required` attribute from all of the params, and retry the parse.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.group(cls=IgnoreRequiredWithHelp)
@click.option('--directory', required=True)
def cli(directory):
    """
    this is a tool that has an add and remove command
    """
    click.echo(directory)

@cli.command()
@click.option('--overwrite', is_flag=True)
def add(overwrite):
    """
    this is the add command
    """
    click.echo("add overwrite={}".format(overwrite))


@cli.command()
def remove():
    """
    this is the remove command
    """
    click.echo('remove')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'add --help',
        '--help',
        '--directory a_dir add'
        '',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> add --help

Usage: test.py add [OPTIONS]

  this is the add command

Options:
  --overwrite
  --help       Show this message and exit.
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  this is a tool that has an add and remove command

Options:
  --directory TEXT
  --help            Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  add     this is the add command
  remove  this is the remove command
-----------
> --directory a_dir add
a_dir
add overwrite=False
```

Comment: For readers who find this question when searching for basic use of required arguments in click:

this solution is only necessary because OP has required arguments at the group level. When required=True at the command level only, --help (no_args_is_help=True) work as expected out of the box.